# jQuery animate scroll auto

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a problem, I just made a piece of code which show images on first click on an element, and hide them on second click. My problem is when the images are totally hidden (width = 0px) after the second click, the page scroll immediately hundreds of pixels above, like an anchor.
I just work on left position and width of the hidden images.

Anyone had the same problem?

**EDIT :**

I tested it again, and I have more details: this problem affect only the first and the third bloc of images (these blocs animation is the reverse animation of the second and fourth blocs), and when the second click append, there's a small scroll when the first image (green_rect_arr_*.png) begin to hide herself, and a second big scroll when the second image (green_link.png) begin to hide herself.

My HTML/CSS:

```
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_circle_rse.png" class="pos_absolute green_circle_rse_waw_hs" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_link.png" class="pos_absolute green_link_rse_waw_hs" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_rect_arr_rse.png" class="pos_absolute green_rect_arr_rse_waw_hs" />

    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_circle_hbp.png" class="pos_absolute green_circle_hbp_waw_hs" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_link.png" class="pos_absolute green_link_hbp_waw_hs" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_rect_arr_hbp.png" class="pos_absolute green_rect_arr_hbp_waw_hs" />

    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_circle_inno.png" class="pos_absolute green_circle_inno_waw_hs" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_link.png" class="pos_absolute green_link_inno_waw_hs" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_rect_arr_inno.png" class="pos_absolute green_rect_arr_inno_waw_hs" />

    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_circle_secu.png" class="pos_absolute green_circle_secu_waw_hs" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_link.png" class="pos_absolute green_link_secu_waw_hs" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/green_rect_arr_secu.png" class="pos_absolute green_rect_arr_secu_waw_hs" />

<style>
.green_circle_rse_waw_hs {

    top: 5vw;
    left: 60vw;
    width: 25vw;
}

.green_circle_hbp_waw_hs {

    top: 40vw;
    left: 15vw;
    width: 25vw;
}

.green_circle_inno_waw_hs {

    top: 75vw;
    left: 60vw;
    width: 25vw;
}

.green_circle_secu_waw_hs {

    top: 110vw;
    left: 15vw;
    width: 25vw;
}

.green_rect_arr_rse_waw_hs {

    top: 0vw;
    left: 15vw;
    height: 34.999vw;
    width: 25vw;
}

.green_rect_arr_hbp_waw_hs {

    top: 35vw;
    left: 60vw;
    height: 34.999vw;
    width: 25vw;
}

.green_rect_arr_inno_waw_hs {

    top: 70vw;
    left: 15vw;
    height: 34.999vw;
    width: 25vw;
}

.green_rect_arr_secu_waw_hs {

    top: 115vw;
    left: 60vw;
    height: 17.499vw;
    width: 25vw;
}

.green_link_rse_waw_hs {

    top: 15vw;
    left: 40vw;
    height: 5.5vw;
    width: 20.8vw;
}

.green_link_hbp_waw_hs {

    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    top: 50vw;
    left: 39.1vw;
    height: 5.5vw;
    width: 21vw;
}

.green_link_inno_waw_hs {

    top: 85vw;
    left: 40vw;
    height: 5.5vw;
    width: 20.8vw;
}

.green_link_secu_waw_hs {

    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    top: 120vw;
    left: 39.1vw;
    height: 5.5vw;
    width: 21vw;
}
</style>
```

And my JS (with jQuery):

```
 $(function() {

        var end_one = true;
        var end_two = true;
        var end_three = true;
        var end_four = true;

        var first_rec = $(".green_rect_arr_rse_waw_hs");
        var second_rec = $(".green_rect_arr_hbp_waw_hs");
        var third_rec = $(".green_rect_arr_inno_waw_hs");
        var fourth_rec = $(".green_rect_arr_secu_waw_hs");

        var first_link = $(".green_link_rse_waw_hs");
        var second_link = $(".green_link_hbp_waw_hs");
        var third_link = $(".green_link_inno_waw_hs");
        var fourth_link = $(".green_link_secu_waw_hs");

        var base_width_first_rec = first_rec.width();
        var str_base_width_first_rec = (base_width_first_rec).toString();
        var left_first_rec = first_rec.position().left;
        var str_left_first_rec = (left_first_rec).toString();
        var width_left_first_rec = (toVw(left_first_rec + base_width_first_rec)).toString() + "vw";

        var base_width_second_rec = second_rec.width();
        var str_base_width_second_rec = (base_width_second_rec).toString();

        var base_width_third_rec = third_rec.width();
        var str_base_width_third_rec = (base_width_third_rec).toString();
        var left_third_rec = third_rec.position().left;
        var str_left_third_rec = (left_third_rec).toString();
        var width_left_third_rec = (toVw(left_third_rec + base_width_third_rec)).toString() + "vw";

        var base_width_fourth_rec = fourth_rec.width();
        var str_base_width_fourth_rec = (base_width_fourth_rec).toString();

        first_rec.css({width: "0px", left: width_left_first_rec});
        second_rec.css({width: "0px"});
        third_rec.css({width: "0px", left: width_left_third_rec});
        fourth_rec.css({width: "0px"});

        var base_width_first_link = first_link.width();
        var str_base_width_first_link = (base_width_first_link).toString();
        var left_first_link = first_link.position().left;
        var str_left_first_link = (left_first_link).toString();
        var width_left_first_link = (toVw(left_first_link + base_width_first_link)).toString() + "vw";

        var base_width_second_link = (second_link.width()).toString();

        var base_width_third_link = third_link.width();
        var str_base_width_third_link = (base_width_third_link).toString();
        var left_third_link = third_link.position().left;
        var str_left_third_link = (left_third_link).toString();
        var width_left_third_link = (toVw(left_third_link + base_width_third_link)).toString() + "vw";

        var base_width_fourth_link = (fourth_link.width()).toString();

        first_link.css({width: "0px", left: width_left_first_link});
        second_link.css({width: "0px"});
        third_link.css({width: "0px", left: width_left_third_link});
        fourth_link.css({width: "0px"});

        $(".green_circle_rse_waw_hs").click(function() {

            if(first_rec.width() < base_width_first_rec && end_one) {

                end_one = false;

                first_link.animate({width: str_base_width_first_link, left: str_left_first_link}, 1000, function() {

                    first_rec.animate({width: str_base_width_first_rec, left: str_left_first_rec}, 1000, function() {

                        end_one = true;
                    });
                });
            }
            else if(end_one) {

                end_one = false;

                first_rec.animate({width: "0px", left: width_left_first_rec}, 1000, function() {

                    first_link.animate({width: "0px", left: width_left_first_link}, 1000, function() {

                        end_one = true;
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        $(".green_circle_hbp_waw_hs").click(function() {

            if(second_rec.width() < base_width_second_rec && end_two) {

                end_two = false;

                second_link.animate({width: base_width_second_link}, 1000, function() {

                    second_rec.animate({width: str_base_width_second_rec}, 1000, function() {

                        end_two = true;
                    });
                });
            }
            else if(end_two) {

                end_two = false;

                second_rec.animate({width: "0px"}, 1000, function() {

                    second_link.animate({width: "0px"}, 1000, function() {

                        end_two = true;
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        $(".green_circle_inno_waw_hs").click(function() {

            if(third_rec.width() < base_width_third_rec && end_three) {

                end_three = false;

                third_link.animate({width: str_base_width_third_link, left: str_left_third_link}, 1000, function() {

                    third_rec.animate({width: str_base_width_third_rec, left: str_left_third_rec}, 1000, function() {

                        end_three = true;
                    });
                });
            }
            else if(end_three) {

                end_three = false;

                third_rec.animate({width: "0px", left: width_left_third_rec}, 1000, function() {

                    third_link.animate({width: "0px", left: width_left_third_link}, 1000, function() {

                        end_three = true;
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        $(".green_circle_secu_waw_hs").click(function() {

            if(fourth_rec.width() < base_width_fourth_rec && end_four) {

                end_four = false;

                fourth_link.animate({width: base_width_fourth_link}, 1000, function() {

                    fourth_rec.animate({width: str_base_width_fourth_rec}, 1000, function() {

                        end_four = true;
                    });
                });
            }
            else if(end_four) {

                end_four = false;

                fourth_rec.animate({width: "0px"}, 1000, function() {

                    fourth_link.animate({width: "0px"}, 1000, function() {

                        end_four = true;
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        function toVw(posPx) {

            var height = $(window).width();

            return (posPx * 100) / height;
        }
)};
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: So you are using "width: 0" to hide your images? why not use "display:none"

Comment: this type ? http://jsfiddle.net/DNNFF/9/

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen I use the width: 0 because I want to animate the link between the bloc (0px to Npx in 1sec) !

Comment: @RaviChauhan No, in your example the scrolling seem logic, here in my code nothing logical can scroll the position of the screen, and the screen go to a position greatly above the blocs !